# Fail on a javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a simple regex for a string that matches http or https.
I started with:

```
#^((http|https)://)"
```

It doesnt work. I want :// also be in the beginig so i put double brackets.
Im a bit newie in regex. Hope you help me.

Comment: How are you applying the regex in your code?

Comment: In JavaScript, it should be `/^((http|https):\/\/)/` (or `new RegExp("^((http|https)://)")`)

Comment: It's not very clear what you want from the regex. Could you show a couple of examples of input that should match or not match the regex?

Comment: `^` matches in the beginning of line only, but of course it cannot be the beginning of line if it is already followed by `#` character...

Comment: As it is now, nothing can surely match that regex, ever.

Comment: If you're using the regex construct, you should use `"https?://"`, but if you're using the regex directly in a string format, you'd use `/https?:\/\//` (note that you have optional `s` in `http`, you can use `?` instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`?` optional operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html):

```
/^(https?)?:\/\//
```

This makes both the `s` after `http` and the whole group optional, allowing the string to begin with `://` directly as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
https?:\/\/
```

meaning:

```
http   - required: "http"
s?     - followed by an optional "s"
:\/\/  - followed by required "://"
```